# Is the ratio trace problem convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a ratio trace problem described as follows:

$\arg\max_{w} \text{trace}((w^tAw)\cdot \text{inv}(w^tBw))$, 
where A and B are full rank matrices.

This problem can be solved via generalized eigenvalue problem.

My question is that is this optimization problem convex or non-convex?

Comment: It is in general non-convex, yes. But what are the dimensions of w? If it is a vector you do not need the trace at all.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. In what instances, it can be convex? The w is a matrix.

Comment: Not in any non-trivial cases I can think of. And what do you mean by division, then, if w is a matrix?

Comment: I have put the brackets inside the trace. So the entire thing inside the bracket is a matrix. Does this problem still a non-convex?

Comment: So the division operator is meant in MATLAB style, then? As in, you are multiplying the first term by the inverse of the second? Because it's a notation error to divide matrices. It's a moot point, though, because there is no way this is convex. Indeed convexity is *rare* and should not be hoped for after the fact; convexity in an optimization model is best *constructed*.

Comment: Yes, it is multiplying the first term by the second term. Sorry about the confusion. I solved this problem using a generalized eigenvalue problem. Is that correct? I just want to make sure this problem is not convex.

Comment: Interesting! I think it would be of interest to the general audience if you would post your solution. Please consider doing so.